# Update Statement returning Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to do a simple update statement but getting the error below.  I have a set of records where there is a critical piece of data missing.  I have a way to get those back so I wanted to use a query like the one below but getting an error.  The query works fine in 2000 but our recently updated 2019 is not allowing it for some reason.

I have verified that there are no duplicate OrderIDs, just duplicate a (from the example below) but that should be allowed since I don't want everything set to the same value.  I have tried putting it all into one statement, moving the data to a table and reading from there and various other methods.

```
Update Orders
Set Orders.a = updatedat.a
From (
    Select OrderID, o2.a
    From Orders o1
        Inner Join Orders2 o2
            On o1.OrderID = o2.OrderID
    Where o1.a is null
    ) updatedat
Where Orders.OrderID = updatedat.OrderID
```

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
> subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
> an expression.

Also just tried this and getting the same message

```
Update Orders
Set a = 201
Where OrderID in 
(100286,100288,100293,100294,100296,100451,100461,100462,100467)
```

Comment: run a select query on the order ID 100286,100288,100293,100294,100296,100451,100461,100462,100467 , find out why there are duplicates, you may need a constraint,

Comment: try this instead of your query. use updated version of join instead of old fashioned join.

Comment: Update Orders
Set Orders.a = updatedat.a
from orders 
join
(
    Select OrderID, o2.a
    From Orders o1
        Inner Join Orders2 o2
            On o1.OrderID = o2.OrderID
    Where o1.a is null
    ) updatedat
on Orders.OrderID= updatedat.OrderID

Comment: Any triggers involved? Typical poorly written trigger error.

Comment: Almost certainly either a bad trigger or a bad function in a computed column. See https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/ As a side point, you don't need to rejoin `Orders` to `updatedat`, you can do `UPDATE updatedat SET...` directly